# Apache camel routes in XML not loaded in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

We migrated Apache Camel version from 3.2 to 3.9.0.
After that,
the routes configured in XML are not loaded.

I have changed the property in the application YAML from
xmlRoutes to
apache.springboot.routes-include-pattern=classpath:camel/routes/*.xml.
But the behavior is very weird,
in local when I run using intellij,
all the routes configured in XML are loaded.
But once the changes are deployed,
only the routes configured by beans are loaded.

The logger says:
No additional RoutesBuilder discovered from: classpath:camel/routes/*.xml

Could you please provide inputs on what might be the issue.

If this issue cannot be resolved,
is there any other way that the route can be configured from the XML.

Comment: Try with Camel 3.10.0 and 3.11.0 when its released (sometime next week)

Comment: Cannot upgrade the Camel version as its not recommended by client. But finally i was able to replicate in local. From the IDEs the issue wasnt replicated, but once I package the jar and run the jar, the xml loading was an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem when migrating from 2.x to 3.x. My XML route folder did not appear to be scanned. What I found was that I needed to migrate the setting from "camel.springboot.xml-routes" to "camel.springboot.routes-include-pattern" as per https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_8.html#_configuration_changes. In your case, the setting should be:

```
camel.springboot.routes-include-pattern=class-path:camel/routes/*.xml
```

Comment: Thank you. we have migrated to a newer version and this problem is resolved.

Comment: Path globbing using wildcard `*` does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the newer version which is 3.11.0, hope it will resolve the issue. Also if you are comfortable with JAVA DSL then start using it, after the 3.0 version camel recommended using Java DSL over XML, which will avoid all these configuration issues.

Comment: We are planning to move to java DSL in future. For the immediate fix, we loaded the XML manually in java.

Answer (score 0):

Other way that the route can be configured from the XML.
Add some properties to **application.properties**

```
camel.springboot.routes-reload-enabled = true
camel.springboot.routes-reload-directory = ./routes
camel.springboot.routes-reload-pattern = "*.xml"
```

Copy routes after application is started

```
SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
FileSystemUtils.copyRecursively(Path.of("./routes_src" ), Path.of("./routes"));
```

It work on 3.19.0 version